# Htaccess URL rewrite, Rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Tried many different variations available on google, stackoverflow, youtube, but still doesn't work for me.

One of examples which I tried to use in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

My url: 
http://mydmain.com/subfolder/?lang=en

I want this url to look like:
http://mydmain.com/subfolder/en

Comment: so you're typing http://mydmain.com/subfolder/en into your browser but nothing is happening?

Comment: Yes. I get 404 not found.

Comment: Your existing rule rewrites `example.com/index/123` to `/index.php?lang=123` is this not what you want?

Comment: I tried access content using url http://mydmain.com/subfolder/en and http://mydmain.com/subfolder/index/en, but they do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule doesn't seem to match any of the URLs that you want to rewrite. First, the rule you have attempts to match `index/`, which doesn't appear at all in the URL that you've provided in the question. Additionally, the second path segment in your URL is `en` but your rule matches *only numbers* (`[0-9]`). Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-z][a-z])$ $1?lang=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The 2 conditions ensures that you don't end up rewriting URLs that already map to content. And the rule has been changed to match whatever URL that ends with a "/en", or any 2 letters other than "en".

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately no success :(

Comment: My url: http://mydmain.com/subfolder/?lang=en
I want this url to look like: http://mydmain.com/subfolder/en
Unfortunately your example doesn't work.

Comment: @LifeIsShort When I type "mydomain.com/subfolder/en" in my browser's address bar, I see in my apache logs that it was rewritten to `/subfolder/?lang=en`.

Comment: Will this rewrite rule work if I use subdomain like http://sub.mydmain.com/subfolder/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type `yourdomain.com/subfolder/en` and it internally goes to `yourdomain/subfolder/?lang=en` , put the following code at your main directory `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ /subfolder/?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So , the above rule will match subfolder/(any letter (capital & smal) or Number )`+` which means Repeats the previous match one or more times then using `?` with or without `/` at the end , which Makes the match optional.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

**Note:** clear your browser cache then test it .